# Twitter API Get User ID from Status ID

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I am creating a `Twitter` bot that will follow the creator of a given status.
I have the status ID (tweet ID), but I need to grab the user ID of the user who posted the tweet in order to follow them. How can I get this? I am using the `Twyton` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the request [`statuses/show/:id`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/statuses/show/%3Aid) as specified in the [`Twitter REST API`](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public)

In [`Twython`](http://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), you should call [`show_status`](http://twython.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=show_status#twython.Twython.show_status) like this:

```
from twython import Twython

# define application keys here
consumer_key = ""
consumer_secret = ""
access_token = ""
access_token_secret = ""

twitter = Twython(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_token_secret)
status = twitter.show_status(id='tweet_id')
print status['user']['id_str']
```